# Modify Field Values in a Nested Array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nested

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("568501dd4b1eaa529a40c3b7"), 
    "Thought" : [
        {
            "thread_id" : "f6a678ed8e45ab22f258020530ddaafc", 
            "th_username" : "Vipul", 
            "th_email" : "abc@abc.com", 
            "th_text" : "original thought", 
            "th_image" : "", 
            "likes" : NumberInt(0), 
            "liked_user" : [], 
            "th_inserted_at" : "18-01-2016 13:31:45", 
            "Comments" : [
                {
                    "comment_id" : "f30937a4e12b0b7c975c172767ce7713", 
                    "cmt_from_id" : "5509dc6dcf5b5b7b8f95f23f041886d3", 
                    "commenter_name" : "Vipul Masurkar", 
                    "commenter_email" : "abc@abc.com", 
                    "comment_txt" : "hello comment", 
                    "cmt_likes" : 2.0, 
                    "cmt_liked_user" : [

                    ], 
                    "cmt_inserted_at" : "18-01-2016 13:31:54"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Document and I want to replace `Thought.Comments.cmt_likes` from 2.0 to something of my wish (eg 4.0)

I can't use `$` operator twice so I can't use `$inc` to increment the value.

Is there any way to modify the nested array fields?
If not possible then can I do it through php atleast?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can access that value like this, assuming that you have it stored in variable *$mydoc*:

```
$mydoc->Thought[0]->Comments[0]->cmt_likes = '4.0';
```

In MongoDB, this should be something like this. I assumed you would need a condition which sub-documents to update, so I used the username *Vipul* for that:

```
db.mydb.update(
    { "Thought.0.th_username": "Vipul" },
    { $set: { "Thought.0.Comments.0.cmt_likes": "4.0" } }
)
```

Comment: if i loop through the Comments array and find cmt_likes your way and modify the data then how would i commit the changes back to the document without changing the order of the Comments array

Comment: thanks i am almost there but i dont know the index specifically.. can you give me a solution using a loop where updae only happens to the right cmt_likes field as the comments array may increase with time

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific about which conditions must be true for an update to happen.